# A suitable OS for running a Java application which captures photos and prints them

Tags: camera, operating-systems, opencv, java, printing

I have developed a Java application, which captures photos from a webcam and detects faces (using OpenCV) and prints only the facial area on paper. Now I have to run this app on a Raspberry Pi. I need a very minimal operating system to run this app. I don't use any monitor with this system, so when I start the machine, app should start automatically. and then app will start functioning, if it detects a face it will print. This machine will be used only used for this app only, so which OS I have to use for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely any OS would do, so long as it supports Java (i.e. it has a JRE), you can specify which binaries execute upon startup and it supports OpenCV - which is all of the common Pi OSes.

As you will only be running this app, you don't need an OS with every service installed, nor would you require a desktop environment, just a minimal setup.

You should google for "lightweight linux for Pi" to see the full range of options, as it is difficult to give you a single answer without it being an opinion. Nevertheless, some of your options would include:

- [Arch Linux](http://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv6/raspberry-pi)
  for Pi is a lightweight option, as is;
- [Snappy Ubuntu
  Core](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi#Snappy_Ubuntu_Core),
  or;
- [Lubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi).